# Search of Procedure Request does not return all key=value pairs updated

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

This is a json file :"ValidProcedureRequest.json"

```
{
  "resourceType": "ProcedureRequest",
  "text": {
    "status": "generated",
    "div": ""
  },
  "occurrenceTming" : {
    "resourceType" : "Timing",
    "event" : ["31-01-2017"],
    "repeat" : {
         "boundsPeriod" : { "start" : "10:55"},
         "period" : 1,
         "periodUnit" : "d",
         "dayOfWeek" : ["mon,wed"],
         "timeOfDay" : ["11::44"]
         }
      },
   "occurrencePeriod" : {
    "start" : "10:55",
    "end" : "22:25"
   },
   "requester": {
    "agent": {
      "reference": "Practitioner/example"
    }
   },
   "intent": "order",
   "performer": {
    "reference": "Practitioner/COREPRACTITIONER1"
    },
   "category": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
          "code": "103693007",
          "display": "Diagnostic procedure (procedure)"
        }
      ],
      "text": "Diagnostics Procedure"
    }
   ],
   "code": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "",
        "code": "303653007",
        "display": "Computed tomography of head"
      }
    ]
  },
  "subject": {
     "reference": "Patient/SL88812358"
 }
}
```

I run CURL command on the ValidProcedureRequest.json file.

```
"curl -X POST https://fhir.dstu2.safetylabs.org/api/smartdstu2/open/ProcedureRequest -H 'Content-type: application/json+fhir' --data ValidProcedureRequest.json
{
"resourceType":"OperationOutcome",
"text":{
"status":"generated",
"div":"<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\ <http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/> "><h1>Operation Outcome</h1><table border=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"font-weight: bold;\">information</td><td>[]</td><td><pre>Successfully created resource "ProcedureRequest/7549/_history/1" in 16ms</pre></td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t</tr>\n\t\t</table>\n\t</div>"
},
"issue":[
{
"severity":"information",
"code":"informational",
"diagnostics":"Successfully created resource \"ProcedureRequest/7549/_history/1\" in 16ms"
}
]"
```

Note: It tells Successfully create.Means all the key has updated in the FHIR database.

I run curl command for Getting the updated object.

```
curl -X GET https://fhir.dstu2.safetylabs.org/api/smartdstu2/open/ProcedureRequest/7549
{
"resourceType":"ProcedureRequest",
"id":"7549",
"meta":{
"versionId":"1",
"lastUpdated":"2017-11-03T13:06:50.000+00:00"
},
"text":{
"status":"generated"
},
"subject":{
"reference":"Patient/SL88812358"
},
"code":{
"coding":[
{
"code":"303653007",
"display":"Computed tomography of head"
}
]
},
"performer":{
"reference":"Practitioner/COREPRACTITIONER1"
}
```

Question : How do I retrieve all the key/values submitted in my GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You have a version issue. You're submitting an R3 version of a procedure request to a server that is running DSTU2, and it's not configured to validate the input. So it's silently dropping all the content that is not known in DSTU2